# You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time ERROR

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make edits to an access report, but I keep running into the error. "You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. If you proceed to make changes, you may not be able to save them later."

I know that no one else is in the database because I am the only person who has access to it. I'm not sure why I keep getting this error, but I have read some that if you close out of the database too many times it may occur. Does anyone have a way to resolve? I even opened in exclusive mode and am getting a similar error - Run-time error '3045'. Could not use *file path* already in use. It's very frustrating. Thank you!

Comment: where is the file location? locally on your machine? use sysinternals "handle" to see what's using the file. on a file server? check the server's share admin to see what/who's using the file.

Comment: yes, it's on my machine

Comment: Could you explain how to check sysinternals "handle"?

Comment: then use [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx). it'll tell you exactly what processes are using the file.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that looks like my db. Not exactly sure what I am searching for though

Comment: `c:\> handle yourdbfile.mdb`, and it'll tell you what's got the file open.